# Virus-scan file with Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, automation, virus-scanning

Is it possible to trigger a virus scan on a file with PowerShell?

We want to search a file for virus, and if the file is ok; move the file to another directory..

We have thought about setting up a dedicated server for this with some software for the virus-search, but we have no clue on where to begin, or if it's even possible. I'm open for suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: ClamAV may be an option, it has a command line scanner that can easily be used from PowerShell.

Comment: The question basically is whether there's an antivirus with a CLI, provided you don't have a specific antivirus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PowerShell to automate the job. However the choice of antivirus application is up to you. As @Joachim already suggested, you may want to try [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/) which is under GPL.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The antivirus we use are System Center Endpoint Protection, is it possible to trigger a file scan there, or should I rather take a look at ClamAV?